# Magento 2 How add to custom attribute placeholder only on create account page?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, html, placeholder

I cannot figure out how I can add placeholder for some custom attribute on create account page.

In this file: `view/frontend/templates/customer/form/register.phtml` i see some code which output html for my attribute:

```
    <?php $customerAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_user_attributes');?>
    <?php if ($customerAttributes): ?>
        <?php $customerAttributes->setObject($block->getFormData())
            ->setEntityType('customer')
            ->setShowContainer(false);?>
        <?php $block->restoreSessionData($customerAttributes->getMetadataForm());?>
        <?= $customerAttributes->toHtml() ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

But how to add the one I need placeholder for my custom attribute I cannot think of and track how this can be done.

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

Show customer attributes in the customer registration form
For showing customer attributes on the registration page, we need to do the following steps:

First, we will add our phtml files to ‘form.additional.info’ reference name using

> Module/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     layout="1column"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                  name="phone_number"
                  template="Magenest_CustomerAttribute::extra_field.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```